# Do I need a visa to transit between separate flights at Baku Airport Azerbaijan

Tags: visas, transit, airports, uk-citizens, azerbaijan

I bought a ticket with Aeroflot from Copenhagen -> Baku (Azerbaijan), and returning from Yerevan (Armenia) to Copenhagen. My plan was to backpack Azerbaijan, Georgia, Armenia.

I have overlooked the visa requirements. It seems getting a visa for Azerbaijan is laborious to say the least. I will not tour Azerbaijan after all.

My new plan: I will just buy a ticket from Baku -> Tbilisi (Georgia) ($120) and tour Georgia and Armenia only.

Am I right in thinking I won't need any visa?

Normally on flights with a connection my luggage is checked through to the end destination, so I don't have to 'arrive' at the intermediate airport, I just go through to the relevant gate. But in this case I will be taking a separate flight, and need to exit to arrivals in order to check in to my flight.

Does anyone have experience of Baku/Azerbaijan, or this scenario at any airport?

If I need a transit visa, should I get on in advance, or expect to get one at the airport if I have an onward ticket?

I have a UK passport.

Comment: Can you tell us how was your trip? Was there any problems in Yerevan having Azerbaijani seal in your passport?

Comment: I went to Morocco instead. No visa problems. I heard the problem was just in Azerbaijan having a stamp from the breakaway Armenian territory.

Answer (score 4):

If you were on a single booking and didn't need to pass through immigration, you could transit without a visa. Timatic tells us that [transit without visa is possible if you remain airside](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=1&HEALTH=1&NA=GB&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=GE&EM=DK&TR=AZ&VT=00&user=STAR&subuser=STARB2C).

Since you are on separate tickets and will need to pass through passport control to collect your luggage and change flights, [you will need a transit visa](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/azerbaijan/entry-requirements). In theory you can obtain one online from a travel agent, though the [website](http://www.visaforazerbaijan.org.uk/) the [embassy recommended](http://www.azembassy.org.uk/index.php/visa-information) doesn't even have an option for transit visas. You might be able to [apply for an e-visa directly](https://evisa.gov.az/en/), rather than through a travel agent.

Comment: I think it might be possible to transfer without luggage while staying airside. Just register for the flight online.

Comment: @alamar Yes, that's possible in most (non-US) airports.

Answer (score 3):

Tourist e-visas for Azerbaijan are now available and cost 24 USD and are ready within 5 business days. There is a short turnaround visa process available also,  which costs 75 USD.